# Do node.js callbacks have to be in a nonce function? If so, why?

Tags: node.js, callback

I try very hard to modularize my code, and so far have done will with avoiding Callback hell. One thing that is annoying me is how when I pass in a callback function, it has to be called from a nonce callback function, like so

```
paramQuery(query, params, callback){
    this.Handle.getConnection(function(err, Connection){

        Connection.query(query, params, function(error, results, rows){             
            callback(error, results, rows); <-- this crap right here
        });

        Connection.release();
    });
}
```

Is it necessary to call the callback in a nonce ALL THE TIME? If I've already defined the callback elsewhere, why can't I just pass it on down the chain?

```
paramQuery(query, params, callback){
    this.Handle.getConnection(function(err, Connection){
        if(err){
            console.error("Could not connect to the Database:\n\n" + err.stack);
            process.exit(1);
        }

        Connection.query(query, params, callback(error, results, rows)); <-- Much cleaner 

        Connection.release();
    });
}
```

Comment: because... you're calling the callbak immediately rather than passing as a function to the query? lose the `(...)`, `Connection.query(query, params, callback)` *Much cleaner*

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the callback *variable* (argument) from the caller to a nested function without declaring a new function or executing it. Take this simple example:

```
var func1 = function(arg, cb) {
    func2(arg * 100, cb)
}

var func2 = function(arg, cb) {
    cb(arg * 20)
}

func1(4, function(result) {
    console.log(result)
    // 8000
})
```

The difference in your example is that you were *executing* the callback (`callback()`) rather than just passing it as a parameter (`callback`):

```
paramQuery(query, params, callback){
    this.Handle.getConnection(function(err, Connection){
        Connection.query(query, params, callback);
        Connection.release();
    });
}
```

Comment: Me either. Plus one for the explanation though

Comment: I got one too, someone angry about callbacks :)

Comment: Rage, rage against callbacks! How dare we write asynchronous code! 

Comment: Well considering the discussion is about node.js, I'd say we dare. We dare indeed. >:D

Answer (score 0):

If the function you are creating and the function to be called have the same signature then you don't need to wrap the function, you can pass the function itself. In your case they are both `(error, results, rows)` so this will work:

```
paramQuery(query, params, callback){
    this.Handle.getConnection(function(err, Connection){
        if(err){
            console.error("Could not connect to the Database:\n\n" + err.stack);
            process.exit(1);
        }

        Connection.query(query, params, callback);

        Connection.release();
    });
}
```

If you passed `callback(error, whatever)` into `Connection.query` as suggested then the function would be called immediately and the result of that function passed as an argument to `Connection.query`

Comment: While your answer is correct, I accepted @brandonscript because it is a bit easier to understand. Nothing personal.